# how to load previous value in select box in angular js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm having a select box which has ng-options. I want to load the previous set value by default. the previous set values is  `{{c.fact}}`. I tried using `ng-value="c.fact"` inside select box, it didn't work. please help me out. Thankyou

```
 <select class="browser-default event sensor" ng-model="sensor"
         ng-options="sensor.uid for sensor in sensors track by sensor.uid"> 
 </select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a value in ng-model in order to have a default selected value.You can initialise your ng-model with c.fact both in your controller or in html.

js

```
$scope.sensor = $scope.c.fact;
```

html

```
<div ng-init="sensor = c.fact">
    <select class="browser-default event sensor" ng-model="sensor" ng-options="sensor.uid for sensor in sensors track by sensor.uid"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help.